# Corona Admobs Integration problems

Tags: lua, admob, coronasdk

my build.settings

```
settings =
{
     orientation =
{
    default = "portrait",

},

android =
{
    versionCode = "11"
},

androidPermissions =
{
    "android.permission.INTERNET",
    "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
    "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE",
    "android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE",
},

build =
{
   neverStripDebugInfo = true
},
plugins =
   {
      ["CoronaProvider.ads.admob"] = 
               { 
                   publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { ["android"] = true }
                 }
   }

}
```

My main.lua

```
local background  = display.newImage("backgroundrain.png")
background.x = display.contentWidth / 2
background.y = display.contentHeight / 2
local provider = "admob"
local appID = ""
local ads = require "ads"
--button
local widget = require( "widget" )
provider = "admob"
appID = ""
AD_TYPE = "banner"
local ads = require( "ads" )

local button1 = widget.newButton
{
defaultFile = "finallpicture.png",
overFile = "finallpicture2.png",
label = "",
emboss = true,
onPress = "finallpicture2.png",
onRelease = "finallpicture2.png",
}
button1.x = 495; button1.y = 950

local theaudio = audio.loadStream("theaudio.mp3")

function button1:touch(e)
 if(e.phase == "ended") then
     audio.play(theaudio)
     end
end      
button1:addEventListener("touch", button1)
local function adListener( event )
-- event table includes:
--      event.provider
--      event.isError (e.g. true/false )

local msg = event.response

-- just a quick debug message to check what response we got from the library
print("Message received from the ads library: ", msg)

if event.isError then
    statusText:setTextColor( 255, 0, 0 )
    statusText.text = "Error Loading Ad"
    statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5

    showAd( "banner" )
else
    statusText:setTextColor( 0, 255, 0 )
    statusText.text = "Successfully Loaded Ad"
    statusText.x = display.contentWidth * 0.5
end
end

-- Initialize the 'ads' library with the provider you wish to use.
if appID then
ads.init( provider, appID, adListener )
end
```

When I run my code i get a pop up window that says "Plugin Download Error" The followign plugin could not be downloaded:
    com.coronalabs/CoronaProvider.ads.admob.

I know i am most likely missing something big here bit i have been trying to debug for days. I read the forum on corona about Corona Admobs Integration but I still cant get it.

I would love some suggestions if you have any.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the docs. Your **build.settings** for the plugin of **adMob** is wrong, according to the [docs](https://docs.coronalabs.com/plugin/ads-admob-v2/index.html) replace:

```
plugins =
   {
      ["CoronaProvider.ads.admob"] = 
               { 
                   publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { ["android"] = true }
                 }
   }
```

with

```
    plugins =
    {
        ["plugin.google.play.services"] =
        {
            publisherId = "com.coronalabs",
            supportedPlatforms = { iphone=false, android=true }
        },
    },      
}
```